# How to stop a user from getting to wordpress' user profile

Tags: php, wordpress, admin

I've just finished a website with admins and users with profiles in wordpress, however, my client wants me to block users from the wordpress user profile. This is whats happening:

A user can just type "http://www.domain.com/wp-admin" and he would get to see the wordpress dashboard, that user can't make any changes and only has acces to the "Dashboard" and "profile" sections which grant him no power.

But my client wants to block the regular user from this page.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Personally, this is why I avoid WP like the plague: the immense difficulty in hiding its admin tools

Comment: See this thread on WPSE: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11244/how-to-restrict-dashboard-access-to-admins-only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use login redirect filter, the below test if the current logged in user role is 'Subscriber', IF so - redirect to some kind of absolute, if you have a member page and you know the ID, you can use `get_permalink()` and return it. If the current user role is 'Administrator', place them on the Dashboard. If it's neither Administrator or Subscriber, OR if we do not know the user role for any reason, redirect them to the front page of our website. You can place the following into your themes `functions.php` file. `wp-content -> themes -> your-theme`

```
/** Redirect Members to Member Pages **/
function member_redirect($redirect, $request, $user)
{
    global $user;
    if(isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles))
    {
        if(in_array("subscriber", $user->roles))
            return "ABSOLUTE_URL_HERE - maybe use get_permalink()";
        else if(in_array("administrator", $user->roles))
            return admin_url('index.php');
        else
            return home_url();
    }
    else{
        return home_url();  
    }
}
add_filter("login_redirect", "member_redirect", 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks man, i'm kinda new to this wordpress thingy, could you tell where should I place this piece code?

Comment: Sorry, you can place it into your themes `functions.php` file

Answer (score 0):

/**
 * Restrict contributors( lowest role) from accessing wordpress admin panel
 */

```
function restrict_user() {

    if ( ! current_user_can('edit_post') ) {
        wp_die( __( 'You are not allowed to access this part of the site' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_user', 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
function restrict_user_wpadmin() {
    if ( ! current_user_can('edit_post') ) {
        wp_redirect( '/' );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_user_wpadmin', 1 );
```